# Python - Print a value without intterupting a loop/function

Tags: python, search, recursion, python-2.7, interrupt-handling

Using Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

I has a recursive function, to find a file in the path, also looking in the sub-folders.

**My Problem:**
During long searches, I wish to see the value of `retval` on `KeyboardInterrupt`.
But the code is raising an error on `KeyboardInterrupt`, as it is interrupting a "deeper" function call/run.

**My Question:**
Is there any way to not interrupt the loop, but still have the values printed,
Or
A different way to do the same (that is not using `KeyboardInterrupt` but something else)

**My Code:**

```
import os

def search(path,filename):
    try:
        global found
        folders = []
        retval = []

        try:    
            for item in os.listdir(path):
                if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, item)):
                    folders.append(os.path.join(path, item))
                else:
                    if item == filename:
                        found += 1
                        retval.append(os.path.join(path, item))
        except WindowsError,e:
            print str(e)[10:]

        for folder in folders:
            retval += search(folder,filename)
        return retval
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print retval

found = 0
path = 'C:\\'
filename = 'test.txt'
print search(path,filename)
```

Comment: Yes, [recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function) is a right word for function, that calls itself.

Comment: @m0nhawk :) Thanks for clearing my doubt. You got 2 rep! :)

Comment: It seems to me that you could register a [signal handler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) to catch `sigint` and print what you want ... I'm not sure how that stuff works on widows though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how or if this would work on windows, but under unix, you could do something like:

```
import signal
import sys

count = 0

def handler(signum,frame):
    global count
    print "Value of 'i' is",i
    count += 1
    if count >= 2:
        sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,handler)
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
```

Here I exit the program after ctrl-C is caught (twice) because I don't have any other good way of exiting the program.

The use of global data here is merely for demonstration purposes -- Out in the wild, I'd use a class and pass an instance-method to the signal handler in order to maintain state between calls.  -- e.g., something like:

```
import signal

class Reporter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.retval = []

    def handler(self,signum,frame):
        print self.retval

r = Reporter()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,r.handler)
```

And then you can just re-bind `self.retval` whenever you enter/exit your function:

```
import os

def search(path,filename):
    global found
    folders = []
    retval = []
    r.retval = retval #<--- Line added

    try:    
        for item in os.listdir(path):
            if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, item)):
                folders.append(os.path.join(path, item))
            else:
                if item == filename:
                    found += 1
                    retval.append(os.path.join(path, item))
    except WindowsError,e:
        print str(e)[10:]

    for folder in folders:
        retval += search(folder,filename)
        r.retval = retval   #<---- Line added
    return retval

found = 0
path = 'C:\\'
filename = 'test.txt'
print search(path,filename)
```

I think I would prefer a non-recursive solution using `os.walk` however:

```
import os

def search(path,filename):
    retval = []
    r.retval = retval

    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
         retval.extend(os.path.join(path,dirpath,item) for item in filenames if item == filename)
    return retval

path = 'C:\\'
filename = 'test.txt'
print search(path,filename)
```

Comment: @Schoolboy -- Check my edit ... Also, now that I'm looking at your code, it seems that `os.walk` would be more appropriate than `os.listdir`.  That would eliminte the need for recursion here which would simplify things just a bit ... (and eliminate a few race conditions while you're at it since you wouldn't need to re-bind `r.retval` all the time)

Comment: Great,  :)   I just made a quick improvisation of your code, by adding 2 lines, such that `found` is also printed below `retval` but there is a small problem, even when there have been files found, `r.retval` is set to `[]` by the latest `search` func.  :(  How to solve that??? And, The loop isn't breaking, is that possible?(it's OK if it isn't but it sure would help)

Comment: @Schoolboy -- That's a tricky one with your recursive way of solving this problem.  Every time you enter `search` again, we bind `r.retval` to the local value of `search` and there's no easy way around that.  The solution is to not write a recursive algorithm which I think should be possible using `os.walk` rather than `os.listdir`.

Comment: Ok, could you give an example of the use of `os.walk`? That should get me started on my next version of the program...

Comment: @Schoolboy -- updated with a solution that I *think* will work (though no guarantees ;-)

Comment: Gr8, that should get me started, Thanks for everything(till now). I'm gonna accept your answer if there are no major developments in the next half hour on this question..

Comment: I just finished!! **THX A LOT**

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `KeyboardInterrupt` handler lower in the hierarchy:

```
for folder in folders:
        try:
             retval += search(folder,filename)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
               print retval
return retval
```

You could test that, although I'm not quite sure how that handles inside a loop like the one you have.

Comment: This will interrupt the loop though.  As soon as KeyboardInterrupt is sent, that current search will be abandoned and so you could change the eventual output.

Comment: Yes I agree with @mgilson, it seems to skip the current folder. Verified.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a more global copy of retval, i would use an attribute of the function, and assign to that when you have a retval that works for you.